# Расскажите, кто как работает в django с формами?

Tags: django

Добрый день, тут хочу для себя разьяснить что лучше, точнее предпочтительнее, "рисовать" самому форму или просто воспользоваться `from django import forms`, а в html просто вывести `{{ form }}`, т.к. и ежу понятно, что если у тебя всего пара полей, то можно особо не выдумывать и вывести через `{{ form }}`, а если у меня десяток полей, где надо ввести и числа и строки и сделать выбор из селектов....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможностей для кастомизации форм довольно много.
В `forms` можно указать нужные виджеты для полей. В темплейтах можно использовать встроенные методы для форм

```
{{ form.as_p }} {{ form.as_table }}
```

Можно обращаться к определенным полям и добавлять их в нужные теги

```
<p>{{ form.some_field }}</p>
```

Можно использовать батарейки, как [crispy_forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Лучше всего почитать [документацию по формам](http://djbook.ru/rel1.7/topics/forms/) и выбрать что то подходящее для вашей проблемы.

Comment: Ну да, документация само сабой, но пока склоняюсь, что мне легче самому отрисовать форму, хотя хочеться делать через forms и тут сразу проблема с css, тк где то легко подключить attrs, а где то, как к примеру с ChoiceField, получаю ошибку object has no attribute 'is_hidden'.

Comment: Синтаксис шаблонизации - jinja?

Comment: @NickVolynkin нет, стандартный

Comment: @Baterson посмотрел. Вроде бы мы оба правы: Jinja - это стандартный синтаксис шаблонизации в Python )) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jinja_%28template_engine%29. Django же на Python

Comment: @NickVolynkin я хотел сказать, что это дефолтный язык шаблонов Django, Jinja надо подключать отдельно `django.template.backends.jinja2.Jinja2`